# Adding vertical-align:middle to intricate divs

Tags: css, html, css-position, vertical-alignment

I have three divs which have a block of text of different lenght. I'd like to vertical-align 'em. I tried with this

```
#container{
    height:200px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
}

#content{
    height:150px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be applied..
**[Here](http://bassano.cngei.it/beta/)**'s my website, the portion I'm talking about is the one with the 3 circles (on hover):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add the following CSS to the `div` that wraps the text on `hover`

```
        /* chrome */
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;

         /* Firefox */
        display: -moz-box;
        -moz-box-pack: center;
        -moz-box-align: center;

        /* IE */
        display: -ms-box;
        -ms-box-pack: center;
        -ms-box-align: center;


        /* Native CSS */
        display: box;
        box-pack: center;
        box-align: center;
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. you mean in addition to the styles I mentioned in my question or just these styles? I tried with just these styles with no luck.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
display: table
```

and

```
display: table-cell
```

on your elements.